# Numpy.reshape for multidimensional Numpy arrays gives same size but different order of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to convert an array of shape `(a, b, c, d)` into a shape `(b*c*d, a)`.

The problem is the output of Array A and B is different:

```
x = np.array([np.arange(1,37)]) #1D array of 1 to 36.
a = 3
b = 2
c = 2
d = 3
Array = np.reshape(x, (a, b, c, d)) #shape (3, 2, 2, 3)

A = poop.reshape(a, b*c*d).T
B = poop.reshape(b*c*d, a)


print("Array shape:" + str(Array.shape))
print(Array)
print("#####")
print("Array A:")
print(A)
print("#####")
print("Array B:")
print(B)
```

I would of thought that Numpy's reshape takes `(row, column)` as input, so reversing then transposing would lead to the same result `(column, row).T`.

Changing the "Order" parameter does not seem to make array B match array A.

Thank you.

The output is:

```
Array shape:(3, 2, 2, 3)
[[[[ 1  2  3]
   [ 4  5  6]]

  [[ 7  8  9]
   [10 11 12]]]


 [[[13 14 15]
   [16 17 18]]

  [[19 20 21]
   [22 23 24]]]


 [[[25 26 27]
   [28 29 30]]

  [[31 32 33]
   [34 35 36]]]]
#####
Array A:
[[ 1 13 25]
 [ 2 14 26]
 [ 3 15 27]
 [ 4 16 28]
 [ 5 17 29]
 [ 6 18 30]
 [ 7 19 31]
 [ 8 20 32]
 [ 9 21 33]
 [10 22 34]
 [11 23 35]
 [12 24 36]]
#####
Array B:
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [10 11 12]
 [13 14 15]
 [16 17 18]
 [19 20 21]
 [22 23 24]
 [25 26 27]
 [28 29 30]
 [31 32 33]
 [34 35 36]]
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand positional arguments for keyword arguments.

Comment: `reshape` is not `transpose`